# NodeJS, Facebook GraphAPI: exchange token for access_token

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking into ["exchange code for access token"](https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-node-sdk#exchange-code-for-access-token) section in nodejs package's documentation.

In the first sample code snippet, it mentions code: 'code'.

```
FB.api('oauth/access_token', {
    client_id: 'app_id',
    client_secret: 'app_secret',
    redirect_uri: 'http://yoururl.com/callback',
    code: 'code'
```

My understanding of this is to get a value to replace 'code'. To get the value, I refer to the 2nd sample code snippet where the author teaches how to extract code out of an URL. However, the URL is predefined with a value.

```
var urlToParse = 'http://yoururl.com/callback?code=.....#_=_';
```

I'm not sure how to get that URL. Could anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to redirect client to OAuth dialog. Once user has authorised your application will receive a callback with `code`.

Also I would highly recommend to read Facebook OAuth flow documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2 before using any SDK.